# Remove specific object from vector list

Tags: c++, stdvector, erase

I'm new to C++, sorry if it's a dummy question.

I'm trying to create a method that would remove a given pointer from a vector, and delete its object. Here's what I have right now:

```
void Engine::destroyObject(GameObject* obj) {

    if (obj == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Error: GameObject pointer given is null!" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    else if (m_GameObjects.empty()) {
        std::cout << "Error: Trying to destroy GameObject while list is empty!" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    auto it = std::remove(m_GameObjects.begin(), m_GameObjects.end(), obj);
    if (it != m_GameObjects.end()) {
        delete obj;
        m_GameObjects.erase(it, m_GameObjects.end());
    }
}

GameObject* Engine::findObject(std::string name) {
    return *std::find_if(m_GameObjects.begin(), m_GameObjects.end(), [name](GameObject* e) { return e->getName() == name; });
}
```

I'm calling those methods like this:

```
GameObject* obj = findObject("Random");
destroyObject(obj);
```

But for some reason, my program crashes at `m_GameObjects.erase(it, m_GameObjects.end());` with the error "vector iterator not dereferencable"

I have tried changing the line to `it = m_GameObjects.erase(it, m_GameObjects.end());` but that did not change anything.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here's a bit more info
GameObject is just a regular class (with some data such as a name...)
The findProject method works fine, it's the line for erase that's causing an error.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98a14577189a140f  Please edit your question to contain a [mcve], which would look something like that link, but contain the code actually necessary to get the same error you do.

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but your `findObject` function has undefined behavior if no object in the vector has the requested name.

Comment: Does the engine have to be involved? If you use `boost::shared_ptr` a the_vector.erase( it ) will get the object destructor called.

Comment: Ok, sorry I just checked and @aschepler you were right, findObject was crashing it because (since I am executing it more than one frame) after deleting it once, it couldn't find it a second time, causing it to crash.

Answer (score 0):

So [aschepler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459640/aschepler) found out that my findObject function was not checking for null values (if the object didn't exist/couldn't be found) so I added some checks and it works now. Thanks a lot!

```
GameObject* Engine::findObject(std::string name) {
    auto it = std::find_if(m_GameObjects.begin(), m_GameObjects.end(), [name](GameObject* e) { return e->getName() == name; });

    if (it == m_GameObjects.end())
        return nullptr;

    return *it;
}
```

I then had to check if the value was a nullptr and not do anything if so.